# Count left join and use it in where

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I currently have the following sql (Generated by typeorm).

```
 SELECT
   "media"."permissionOwner" AS "media_permissionOwner",
   "media"."permissionGroup" AS "media_permissionGroup",
   "media"."permissionOther" AS "media_permissionOther",
   "media"."id" AS "media_id",
   "media"."filename" AS "media_filename",
   "media"."mime" AS "media_mime",
   "media"."description" AS "media_description",
   "media"."length" AS "media_length",
   (
      SELECT
         1 
      FROM
         "user" "user" 
      WHERE
         "user"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1
   )
   AS "user" 
FROM
   "media_object" "media" 
   LEFT JOIN
      "media_object_groups_group" "media_groups" 
      ON "media_groups"."mediaObjectId" = "media"."id" 
   LEFT JOIN
      "group" "groups" 
      ON "groups"."id" = "media_groups"."groupId" 
   LEFT JOIN
      "media_object_owner_user" "media_owner" 
      ON "media_owner"."mediaObjectId" = "media"."id" 
   LEFT JOIN
      "user" "owner" 
      ON "owner"."id" = "media_owner"."userId" 
WHERE
   (
      "media"."permissionGroup" >= $2 
      AND 
      COUNT("groups") = 0 -- How can I accomplish this
   )
   OR 
   (
      "media"."permissionGroup" >= $3 
      AND groups @ > user_groups
   )
   OR 
   (
      owner @ > ARRAY[user] 
      AND "media"."permissionOwner" >= $4
   )
   OR "media"."permissionOther" >= $5   -- PARAMETERS: [23,4,4,4,4]
```

The problem is, I can't use HAVING, because it doesn't seem like it support this type of condition making like WHERE does.

I tried it with a subquery at the COUNT part, but than I can't access the "groups" alias inside the sub select count query.

I am not even sure if the other part of the query works, but first I want to solve the "count" issue.

Comment: Are you trying to find instances where the `group` table doesn't have a matching row?  If so, replace that count line in your filter with `and group.id is null`.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @Andrew The media_object table has a many to many relation ship with group and I want to find where the many to many relation ship is empty. Does this still work with NULL or what happens if you join a table and there is no relation ship?

Comment: The null logic will return rows from your media table that do not have a corresponding row in the group table.

Comment: So `COUNT("groups") = 0` is the same like `"groups" is null` ?